# SQL: Retrieve Distinct for different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, distinct-values

I have the following scenario:

In a SQL-Table I have the following columns:

```
|----------------------------------------|-------------------------------------|
|      Col 1                             |     Col 2                           |
|----------------------------------------|-------------------------------------|
| 4BAEFCAD-0B61-E911-B26B-005056872FC1   | 855757A6-0D61-E911-B26B-005056872FC1|
|----------------------------------------|-------------------------------------|
| 855757A6-0D61-E911-B26B-005056872FC1   | 4BAEFCAD-0B61-E911-B26B-005056872FC1|
|----------------------------------------|-------------------------------------| 
| D2ADDEF8-A3A8-E911-B272-005056872FC1   | CED9DFD0-35A9-E911-B272-005056872FC1|
|----------------------------------------|-------------------------------------|
```

The first two rows are kind of referencing to the same records because they contain the same values for row1 and row 2 but swapped.

Is there an sql-way of only retrieving one of those two colums?? so that in the end I receive the following result:

```
|----------------------------------------|-------------------------------------|
|      Col 1                             |     Col 2                           |
|----------------------------------------|-------------------------------------|
| 4BAEFCAD-0B61-E911-B26B-005056872FC1   | 855757A6-0D61-E911-B26B-005056872FC1|
|----------------------------------------|-------------------------------------| 
| D2ADDEF8-A3A8-E911-B272-005056872FC1   | CED9DFD0-35A9-E911-B272-005056872FC1|
|----------------------------------------|-------------------------------------|
```

THX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple method is:

```
select col1, col2
from t
where col1 < col2
union all
select col1, col2
from t
where col2 > col1 and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.col2 = t.col1 and t2.col1 = t.col2);
```

This has the advantage of preserving the original rows.  If you don't care about the ordering:

```
select distinct (case when col1 < col2 then col1 else col2 end) as col1,
       (case when col1 < col2 then col2 else col1 end) as col2
from t;
```